# Get "closest" Key in Visual Basic Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

In Visual Basic I have a Dictionary which holds a Date as a key and a custom class as value (I will use a String in the example).
I keep track of a list where a date is saved with a value.
For example, lets say I have a dictionary with the following values:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of Date, String)
    dict.Add(DateTime.Now, "test one") // Suppose the time of this date is 12:03:10
    dict.Add(DateTime.Now, "test two") // Suppose the time of this date is 13:07:20
    dict.Add(DateTime.Now, "test three") // Suppose the time of this date is 14:15:30
    dict.Add(DateTime.Now, "test four") // Suppose the time of this date is 15:19:40
```

Now the system gives me a date which does not have a value, but needs one similar to the first previous date.
Let's say I get the date with time 14:00:00, I will need the value of "test two" because 13:07:20 is the first key lower than 14:00:00 (a key which is not actually available in the dictionary keys).

Assuming that the list could be very big, is there a way/what would be the best way to find the key I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Couldnt post on my own question within 8 hours...)

Using my dictionary and using the dict.Keys I did:

```
Dim lookupDate As Date = Date.Parse("01/01/2008 12:17:39")

Dim query = dict.Keys.AsQueryable().Where(Function(singleKey) singleKey < lookupDate)
Dim result As String = query.Last().ToString()
```

This solution should have better performance because of the iQueryable if im correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `Keys` method will give you an array containing all the keys.

```
Dim k As Variant
k = dict.Keys
```

You can then loop through that array to find the key that satisfies the criterion. Here's an example, not thoroughly checked...

```
Dim myDate As Variant
Dim myKey As Variant
myDate = 1234 ' or whatever your target date is
Dim i As Long
myKey = k(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(k)
    If k(i) < myDate And k(i) > myKey Then
        myKey = k(i)
    End If
Next i
```

`myKey` should now contain the key that satisfies your criterion.

Comment: But I am trying to look for a key that does not exist. So it needs to find the key that is the closest lower key than it.

Comment: That's why I say loop through the array until you find the key that satisfies that criterion: largest key that is smaller than some value. I added an example of how to do this.